# How to implement the function into the main

Tags: java, function, geometry

So I have a working code that asks the user the height & width of a rectangle and then outputs the rectangle in asterics (*).

Now I want to implement a **function** `public static int askPositiveInteger(String question, String messageIfError) {...}` that uses `scanner.hasNextInt()` (checks for integer) and `scanner.next()` (throw away whatever nonsense the user wrote).

The function is supposed to ask the user for a positive integer using the message `question`. If the input is wrong it prints the error message `messageIfError` and asks again.

I wrote the function:

```
public static int askPositiveInteger(String question, String messageIfError) {
    int num = -1;
    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer number: ");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            num = scan.nextInt();
        } else {
              System.out.println("I need an int, please try again.");
              scanner.next();
          }
    } while (num <= 0);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to implement it into my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int height, width, i, j;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the height of the rectangle: ");
    height = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
    width = scanner.nextInt();

    for(i = 1; i <= height; i++){
        for(j = 1; j <= width;j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    System.out.print("\n");
    }
scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function dosen't really use the parameters `String question` and `String messageIfError`. You can integrate them in you function by just swap out the

`System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer number: ");` and
`System.out.println("I need an int, please try again.");`

with

`System.out.print(question);` and `System.out.println(messageIfError);`.

this would result in :

```
public static int askPositiveInteger(String question, String messageIfError, Scanner scan) {
    int num = -1;
    while(num <= 0){
        System.out.print(question);
        num = scan.nextInt();
        if(num <= 0){
            System.out.println(messageIfError);
        }
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    return num;
}
```

I changed the function also, that you take an existing Scanner and scan of the given one.

Implementing this new function in your Main-Programm would look like follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int height, width;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    height = askPositiveInteger("Enter the height of the rectangle: ","I need an int, please try again.", scan);
    System.out.println("h = " + height);
    width = askPositiveInteger("Enter the width of the rectangle: ","I need an int, please try again.", scan);
    scan.close();

    for(int i = 1; i <= height; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= width;j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Is that roughly what you thought of?